# PHP How To Display HTML+PHP Code Stored in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store HTML and PHP in a MySQL text field and display it in PHP.

When it displays on site it renders as commented out tags:

```
<!--?php
if(isset($sp_msg) && $sp_msg != ''){ 
print '<div-->
```

This of course screws the whole page up.

How am I supposed to go about displaying this data correctly?  I would like to eventually add this to a full functioning CMS so I would like to understand how to do this correctly.

**page.php**

```
<?php
require_once('library/autoload.php');
$pid = $_REQUEST['id'];
$page = $ct->get_page_info($pid);
$sp_msg = $page['special_msg'];
require_once('h.php');
?>
<div id="row">
    <?php
        print $page['page_content'];
    ?>
</div>
<?php
require_once('f.php');
?>
```

**'page_content' stored in mysql as text**

```
<h3>MY HEADER TEXT</h3>
<?php
if(isset($sp_msg) && $sp_msg != ''){    
    print '<div>'.$sp_msg.'</div>';     
}
?>
<hr>
<p>paragraph text</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to eval the stored php code. When you print out the string stored in the MySQL you don't run it, you only print it.

```
<div id="row">
    <?php
        eval($page['page_content']);
    ?>
</div>
```

**Warning:**
I really don't recommend it. If any suspicious code can be entered into that DB it could cause really big problems. You can't check the PHP code if its not a crypto virus for example. This code will execute anything on the server.

See the PHP manual: [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: Seconding the warning: executing code from external source is a really ***dangerous*** idea. Use your database for data, not code!